# trying to understand the jwt authentication flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

so i'm trying to understand the flow of jwt authentication, and i have some holes, this is what i got:

1. user logins
2. user gets jwt access token and refresh token(server doesn't keep any of them)
3. access token lasts for 5 mins and refresh token for 7 days
4. access token expires
5. user sends refresh token to server
6. server checks:

   - if the access token's(the expired one) user id == refresh token's user id
   - verifies that the refresh token isn't expired
   - maybe verifies that the access token is expired(not sure)
7. if all those conditions are ok, the server sends a new access token to the client
8. user proceeds as usual
9. refresh token expires
10. refresh token needs verification to send a new one

My questions are:

1. how do the user finds out that the access token expired?
   maybe the client app counts the minutes?
   or maybe client tries to use the access token and then get a "token expired" response?
2. are all the conditions in step 6 enough? 
   what if someone gets the refresh token from the client, how do i protect against that?
   also does condition 3 supposed to be checked?
3. how does the server verifies the refresh token?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. No, this is not the client who check the token expiration, this is a server side operation. And no, of course, this is not the client app who check the expiration, counting the minutes. Yes client send a token and get a possible "token expired" response.
2. Simple like that, if the token is valid, you're good to go. If not (expired, wathever) you're not. The expiration date is in the token payload itself. And you are supposed to encrypt your transmission between server and client.
3. The server verify the refresh token the same way he verify any token. Verification usually on login/password on user database to check authorization. This is just a facility to renew a jwt token.

To sum up, the jwt authentication flow is simpler than that:

1. The client send a request with authentication
2. The server respond with an accreditation token
3. The client use that token to dialog with the app
4. If jwt token expires, client sends a refresh token to renew it (optional)

Answer (score 2):

A JSON Web Token consists of 3 parts, i.e. Header, Payload and Signature. Header and Payload are not encrypted rather just encoded (base64), meaning that a client can simply decode these parts.

So to answer your first question -> the client would simply decode the payload part and read the exp-property from the [registered claims](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1). If you're using the [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) library this would look something like:

```
// get the decoded payload and header
var decoded = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
console.log(decoded.header);
console.log(decoded.payload)
```

In order for the server to verify the token, you must provide the secret or the public key from the key pair which was used to sign the JWT. Using node-jsonwebtoken this would work as follows:

```
// verify a token asymmetric
const cert = fs.readFileSync('public.pem');  // get public key
jwt.verify(token, cert, function(err, decoded) {
  console.log(decoded.foo) // bar
});

OR

// verify a token symmetric using secret
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'mySecret');
```